# Creating a simple form with checkboxes which i cant get to pass the correct URL

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, search, checkbox

I can't seem to fix this (what I know is pretty simple) problem.

I'm creating a simple **tag search** that will search venues on my website. 
It's set up so when multiple tags are selected it will bring back all results that have **all** the tags assigned to them. So I need some simple code that displays checkboxes on the homepage and alters the URL to

```
.../placecategory/venue/?place_tags=place+venue
```

I've come up with the following code (with just 2 options, for now) just to get it working

```
<form 
  action="<?php bloginfo('home') ?>/placecategory/venue/?place_tags=hall+stage" 
         method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <h2>Search</h2>
       <input type="checkbox" value="hall" name="place_tags">
       <label for="tag-105">hall</label>
       <input type="checkbox" value="stage" name="place_tags">
       <label for="tag-104">stage</label>
       <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

The problem with this is it's changing the URL to

```
 .../placecategory/venue/?place_tags=hall&place_tags=stage
```

which isn't pulling up the results on my site. How can i change this **so that it removes the second** `&place_tags=` (and every one after that)?

I can tell that i'm missing something silly but it's really frustrating me!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ideally you should submit the form and handle the request as a POST

Comment: Don't do that. Fix the server side script so it expects the data in the format that forms use by default. Otherwise you end up depending on JS and you really don't need to. (PHP is weird though, it won't let you access all the data unless you end the duplicate names with `[]` or ignore `$_GET` and access the raw URI … so rename the fields to end in `[]`).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 <form action="<?php bloginfo('home') ?>/placecategory/venue" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <h2>Search</h2>
      <input type="checkbox" value="hall" name="place_tags[]">
      <label for="tag-105">hall</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="stage" name="place_tags[]">
      <label for="tag-104">stage</label>
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
 </form>
```

Comment: Sorry, i may not be being very clear, i dont want to have the checkboxes ticked on load. I mean when the customer searches by selecting a number of checkboxes instead of it trying to load place_tags=xxx&place_tags=yyy&place_tags=zzz i want it to load place_tags=xxx+yyy+zzz

Comment: You could easily send the request as an array. And use php to loop through  the array. Send the request as a post, that is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse thru this values with JS and put them into hidden input at once.

Try this:

include jQuery library to the head section:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

then in the body section

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       function submit_me() {
                var values = $.map($("input.get-me:checked"),function(input){
                      return input.value;
                  });

                $('#hidden-input').val(values.join('+'));

                $('#your-form').submit();
      };

 </script>

       <input class="get-me" id="tag-105" type="checkbox" value="hall" name="one" />
       <label for="tag-105">hall</label>
       <input class="get-me" id="tag-104" type="checkbox" value="stage" name="two" />
       <label  for="tag-104">stage</label>
       <img width="50" height="50" src="get.png" onClick="submit_me()" />


        <form id="your-form" action="<?php bloginfo('home') ?>/placecategory/venue/" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" value="" name="place_tags" />
        </form>
```

assign to your inputs class="get-me" and put your image into img. You have to only test this on other browsers then FF. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am not great with javascript, any tips? Thanks